# how to place a image on exact location on another image?

Tags: java, android

how to place an image on the exact location on another image in android.
I have tried this using bitmap and canvas but I couldn't locate the second image exact location that I need.

[image: image01]

This is how I Tried.

```
 public Bitmap getNewBitmap()
    {    
    Bitmap backImage=BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(),R.drawable.map);
    Bitmap originalImg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(),R.drawable.point);
    Bitmap mutableBitmap = backImage.copy( Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);

    final Paint paint = new Paint();

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImg, 100, 50, paint);

    return mutableBitmap;
}
```

Comment: No link in your question, edit it.

Comment: @Sam now its oky.

Comment: so you want to replace that map image with another image?

Comment: I have two images one is Map and other one Pointer. I need to point the exact location of the map.